POSIX file-descriptor positions
Suppose that I have C program using POSIX extensions, there is a FILE *fp and its file-descriptor int fd.  May I assume that the "file position" of fd (as per lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR)) should match that of fp (as per ftell(fp))?  By "assume" I mean that "POSIX requires that ..."

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_05_01 describes what has to be done between using one handle and another on the same underlying file.

(it doesn't sound like you can make any such assumption)

The POSIX description of ftell() makes no reference to how it corresponds to lseek() on the underlying FD.

So if I read that right, if I write to the FILE *fp, then if I want the int fd to be at the same position, I should get the position from FILE *fp and set it for int fd (with possibly a fflush thrown in ...)

@jjg, mind if I ask if there's a reason you'd like to use both?

I'm doing some work on an Octave C/C++ extension, Octave handles its C++ iostreams internally but exposes the file descriptors -- I wanted to do some work on a file in Octave, to write some data to it then frewind,  then to access the results in C++ via the descriptor, so an fdopen on it and read (actually pass on to a library to read).  But I find that the stream is at the end of the file to my surprise and alarm.  Then I thought, am I making an unjustified assumption here? And it seems I was ...

@jjg, urgh... So there's the added complication of playing with what Octave gives you, instead of even accessing the standard library directly, right? Though the docs make it look like it pretty much exposes the stdio interface, so you might hope it follows the same rules and calling fflush() there would help.

@ilkkachu -- urgh indeed, I could get the Octave iostream corresponding to the descriptor in the Octave C++ API, but of course there's no way to get a FILE* from that (at least not until C++26, even then only maybe), and I must have a FILE* to pass to the (C) library ... all fun and games!

I think it's safe to say you can assume there are situations where they don't match.
The obvious case being read-ahead: stdio usually reads a block of some kilobytes, regardless of how many bytes the application asks for. Then, ftell() will tell the position according to how much the application code read, while lseek() will tell the position according to how much stdio read from the OS.
Try something like this:
$ cat > seek.c <<'EOF'
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char buf[123];
int main(void) {
    int fd = fileno(stdin);
    fread(buf, 12, 3, stdin);
    long pos1 = ftell(stdin);
    long pos2 = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
    printf("ftell: %ld lseek: %ld\n", pos1, pos2);
    return 0;
}
EOF
$ gcc -Wall -o seek seek.c
$ ./seek < dummyfile
ftell: 36 lseek: 4096

Similarly due to write buffering where the low-level fd position would lag behind the stdio file position.
As mentioned in the comments, the standard has instructions on what to do when accessing a single file through multiple handles (fds or stdio streams). There are several steps to take for different situations, but by my reading it appears to boil down to:

make sure the previously-used handle has cleared all buffers it keeps (e.g. fflush(), regardless of if it was used for reading or writing).
call fseek() or lseek() on the next-to-be-used handle.

Personally, I would avoid getting into that mess.
